# wp-cli: how to render a post with shortcode in HTML

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

By default, “wp-cli get” does not render shortcodes.

I want to render the shortcodes in HTML, to check what the end-user sees in her browser.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [wp-cli/restful](https://wp-cli.org/restful/).

```
# installing restful
wp-cli package install wp-cli/restful

# rendering a post containing a shortcode
wp-cli rest post list --slug=example-post-containing-short-code --field=content
```